# How can I eliminate a sub column and/or convert a sub column to column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I tried to convert a sub column to a main column, but couldn't do so.
Can someone help me on this.

The data I have into BI from the server is,

```
 | Sl No.   |          Sales 1           |           Sales 2           |
 |          | 1 Qtr | % Qtr  | % Change  | 2 Qtr| % Qtr |   % Change   |
 |   1      |  134  |   67   |  12.5     | 175  |  11   |     12.5     |
 |   2      |  255  |   32   |   10      | 123  |  21   |     10       |
 |   3      |  109  |   61   |   11      | 178  |  16   |     11       |
 |   4      |  501  |   22   |   23      | 609  |  33   |     23       |
 |   5      |  221  |   18   |   18      | 306  |  55   |     18       |
```

Since I have "% Change" sub columns twice (duplicate), I want make it as one and preferably as main column.

The expected results should look like,

```
 | Sl No.   |    Sales 1     |    Sales 2    |   % Change   |
 |          | 1 Qtr | % Qtr  |  2 Qtr| % Qtr |              |
 |   1      |  134  |   67   |  175  |  11   |     12.5     |
 |   2      |  255  |   32   |  123  |  21   |     10       |
 |   3      |  109  |   61   |  178  |  16   |     11       |
 |   4      |  501  |   22   |  609  |  33   |     23       |
 |   5      |  221  |   18   |  306  |  55   |     18       |
```

Comment: is it possible for you to share the model? I dont understand what you mean by making it a main column

Answer (score 0):

After you imported your dataset into Power BI you can delte a column in the query editor (`Home > Manage Columns > Remove Columns`). Just select the column and chose remove columns.

And if you want to combine (merge) two columns to one column, go to `Add Column > Custom Column` and create a new column with the following code:

```
= [Column1] & [Column2]
```

In the end close & apply your final dataset.